# Google script HTML api can´t process file upload field

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a simple web app in google scripts with the HTML api.

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function processForm(formObject) {
    var formBlob = formObject.myFile;
    var driveFile = DriveApp.createFile(formBlob);
    return driveFile.getUrl();
}
```

index.html

```
<script>
    function updateUrl(url) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
}
</script>
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="myFile" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit"
    onclick="google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
    .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

The form fails to submit. I´m using google chrome Versión 30.0.1599.101 m
This appears in the console: Uncaught NetworkError: Form submission failed.

Here is the app: https://script.google.com/d/1yrgM20n1ZI99bChN2qtQWgGck36OccLN3A16Gn7tCPvsJw0EcK_ql7C5/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add `encoding="multipart/form-data"` attribute to `form` tag.

Comment: I added in the change to the script, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Umm... I got same error in similar case. then I've fixed by it. BTW, another user resolve it by cut off any chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If not solved already – did you try changing the input type from "button" to "submit"? On top of that I'd also try giving it another value than "Submit" since that might interfere with the actual submit parameter.